# I am calculating page load time using javascript. But unfortunately I am getting it in negative value.

Tags: javascript, page-load-time

I am calculating page load time using JavaScript. But unfortunately I am getting it in negative value.

```
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
```

Output:
-51236723

Comment: has the page finished loading at the given point? Does it yield the same result when typed into console?

Comment: Yes @AlekseiMaide

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to execute this code after `onload` is called.

```
window.onload = function() {
  const performanceTiming = performance.timing;
  const navigationStart = performanceTiming.navigationStart;
  const loadEventEnd = performanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventEnd;
  const pageLoadTime = loadEventEnd - navigationStart;
  console.log({pageLoadTime});
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try with this @Shahdab Aalam Saifi

```
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
var pageloadtime = (loadTime/1000) ; //returns the seconds
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I think both codes are same. I have figured out that I am getting negative value because that piece of code is executed when domContentLoadedEvent is not available. For avoiding issue we can use setTimeout() to wait for sometime.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.